# line integral of a curve in 3D

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the line integral from 
$\left ( 1,0,0 \right )\rightarrow \left ( 1,1,0 \right )$

The function is $\vec{v}=\left \langle x^{2},2yz,y^2 \right \rangle$

Attempt:

$\left ( 1,0,0 \right )\rightarrow \left ( 1,1,0 \right )$

$d\vec{l}=0dx\hat{x}+dy\hat{y}+0dz\hat{z}$
here, x=1 and z-0

$\vec{v}.d\vec{l}=\left \langle x^{2},2yz,y^{2} \right \rangle.\left \langle 0,dy,0 \right \rangle=\left \langle 0,2yzdy,0 \right \rangle$

$\int_{0}^{1}2yzdy=z
$

but z is zero

The line integral is 0.

I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: You're notation is a bit strange but it looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same result.
\begin{align}
I 
&= \int\limits_{C{a\to b}} v \cdot du \\
&= \int\limits_{t_a}^{t_b} v \cdot \dot{u}\, dt \\
&= \int\limits_0^1 (x^2, 2yz, y^2)^T \cdot (d/dt) (1,t,0) \, dt \\
&= \int\limits_0^1 (1, 0, t^2)^T \cdot (0,1,0) \, dt \\
&= \int\limits_0^1 0 \, dt \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Comment: So we've established that is is mathematically correct that the line integral is zero. But physically, there is a movement along the line over which we integrate so why is it zero?

Comment: The field $v$ is orthogonal to $\dot{u}$, so only zero contributions are added up along $u(t)$.